# Windows 10 bug cmd invisible

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, console

When I launch cmd on windows 10 the console is invisible (a black blank screen). Whatever I type is not seen. But when I typed command `color 0a` the screen appeared and text was shown with no cursor.

But when I launched cmd from powershell it behaved normally!

Please help me to understand is this a bug and if it is then how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure your shortcut has the below properties

[image]

Path to the shortcut will be something along the lines of `c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools`

Comment: I would suggest to edit these settings from the cmd window itself. That way, you are ensured that you got the right settings. As in, start cmd, click the icon in the upper-left, select properties to get to the above window. Then on the Colours tab, ensure that the Screen Text and Screen Background are setup properly, and also ensure that the colors themselves are as in the screenshot.

Comment: Surely if the shortcut has other properties specified, they over-ride what's set from that right-click > properties dialog? Or do those properties write back to the shortcut?

Comment: Neither. Windows keeps these settings in the registry, and it depends on how cmd was launched which settings are affected. If you double-click a batch file, it will still launch that command prompt, but different settings are applied. By first launching the batch file, then going to the settings as described in my earlier comment, you ensure that you edit the correct window still.